# Standalone web apps with IIS Express

Tags: web-applications, web, iis-express

Is it possible to redistribute and install .NET 4, IIS Express and SQL Server Express so I can distribute web apps as a standard desktop app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redistribute IIS Express. Please refer to http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/

From the following it looks like you can redistribute SQL server express and .Net as well.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-redistribute.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480198.aspx#netfx30_topic11